# Display Logo and Nav on same bar

Tags: html, css

I'm having a total brain fart and can't figure out how to display my title/logo and navigation on the same line in my html code.  I want the title/logo to be on the left and the nav to be on the right.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Homegrown</h1>
    </div><!--/.title-->
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Services</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!--/.nav-->
</div><!--/.header-->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.title {display:inline; float:left; margin:0 auto;}
.nav {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 1.7%;
    padding:25px 2%;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
ul {display:inline; float:right; list-style:none;}
li {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **.nav** selector remove width: 100%; , change float: left to float: right and (if you want) change padding:25px 2%; into padding:0 2%;

```
.nav {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    /*width:100%;*/
    margin: 0 1.7%;
    /*padding:25px 2%;*/
    padding: 0 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4svrN/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding will work
Demo http://jsfiddle.net/vFgke/

```
.title {display:inline; float:left; margin:0 auto;}
.nav {
    display:inline;
    float:right;

    margin:0 1.7%;

    margin-bottom:0;
}
ul {display:inline; float:right; list-style:none;}
li {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {
width: 100%;
}
.title {
display:inline; 
float:left; 
margin:0 auto;
}
.nav {
display: inline;
float: right;
padding: 25px 2%;
}
}
ul {display:inline; float:right; list-style:none;}
li {display:inline;}
```